# Error : No providers for Component

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have a directive where I defined a radio button and I want to call a method of a component ..
Whene I inject the component in constructor I got this error : `ERROR Error: No provider for FoldersComponent!`

**directive.ts**

```
   import { FoldersComponent } from '../folders/folders.component';
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

declare var jQuery: any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[icheck]'
})

export class IcheckDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  @Output('icheck')
  callComponentFunction: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private parentCmp: FoldersComponent) {
    jQuery(this.el.nativeElement).iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-aero',
      radioClass: 'iradio_square-aero'
    }).on('ifChecked', function(event) {
      if (jQuery('input').attr('type') === 'radio') {
        this.parentCmp.selectType();
      }
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  }
}
```

folder.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-folders',
  templateUrl: './folders.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./folders.component.css'],
})
export class FoldersComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {  }

  selectType() {
    //    alert();
    console.log("Ici");
  }
}
```

folder.component.html

```
<input type="radio" icheck name="filters.type" [(ngModel)]="filters.type"                   value="IN"> (IN)
```

My @NgModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    FoldersComponent,
  ],
```

Comment: It should work https://plnkr.co/edit/ecPrqOp4nDIG71vo4ksT?p=preview

Comment: So cool ... thx ..; I don't understant in my code when I remove parameters of my constructor `private parentCmp: FoldersComponent`, it is work but when I add it for using method of component I got error .. very funny ..

Comment: Thxxx so much It is work

Comment: @yurzui Could you explain us how did you fix ?

Answer (score 5):

It seems you have missed to register `FoldersComponent`  to `@NgModule({})`

Can you post your main file where you have used `NgModule`

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue. Turns out I had missed updating the following in my code:

1. `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`
   in the .ts file of the component that you want to import.
2. Add the component in the NgModule of your appModule.

Answer (score 1):

try this, you have not imported your component.

```
import {  FoldersComponent  } from '../path/to/component
constructor(private _foldersComponent : FoldersComponent){}
@Directive({
selector: '[icheck]'

})
 ... rest of file
```

Then to call methods from  FoldersComponent just use _foldersComponent.

For example, `this._foldersComponent.someMethod()`

Comment: You shouldn't provide component in providers array if you want to have existing reference to component